# Pausing/sleeping threads in java

Tags: java, java-threads

I'm writing a Java program and I want to pause a Thread when the user presses a button. Is there a predefined method I can call from outside of the Thread to temporarily pause the Thread for a set time or a method that just pauses the thread? I.o.w. a sort of '.sleep(int)' that could be called from outside of the Thread.
Thanks.

Comment: There is no safe way to pause a thread ... apart from having the thread pause itself ... at a safe position.  (There is `Thread.pause()` but it is deadlock-prone AND it is deprecated for removal in a future Java release.)

Comment: Do you want to pause for a time duration or when the user presses a button again?

Comment: Always search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting.